# sp_depends output in a table

Tags: sybase

I need to run `sp_depends` on multiple stored procedures on Sybase to get dependencies. Since I have a lot of stored procedures, I wanted to know if there is any way to force `sp_depends` output into a temp table and then select from there all dependent objects. If this is possible, I can just run `sp_depends` from a stored procedure for multiple stored procedures and get the result set in one go.

I tried below without any luck (using Toad):

```
Insert #test_tbl
exec sp_depends sp_proc
```

Above gives error as:

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'"

Please advise if there is any other efficient way to do this. My goal is to get all dependencies for analysis.

**Update**:
I do have a way to generate mass 'sp_depends' in excel. Looking for something to run them in one go and get the whole output of supplied objects.
Also, since this is Sybase utility, unfortunately I don't have a way to edit it

Answer (score 1):

A script like this could help you:

```
isql -Usa -S${ASE_Servername} <<EOF
$password

set nocount on
go
select 'sp_depends '+name from <dbname>..sysobjects
where type='P' and name in ( <list_of_SPs> )
go

EOF
```

Comment: This will only print out a list of sp_depends statements, which is at least better than manually typing in the commands, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Sybase version of T-SQL does not support `INSERT INTO ... EXEC` syntax.  There appears to be no way to do this directly in T-SQL; you'd need to write a script for it.

Having said that, you may be able to use the code shown in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570045/1595565)